# fastapi uvicorn No module named 'asgiref.typing'

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I have created a simple `fastapi` application. Once I want to serve it with `uvicron` I got this error;

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asgiref.typing'
```

I have installed it via conda python 3.8.12. those packages were installed

```
  asgiref            pkgs/main/noarch::asgiref-3.4.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  click              pkgs/main/noarch::click-8.0.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  h11                pkgs/main/noarch::h11-0.12.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  importlib-metadata pkgs/main/win-64::importlib-metadata-4.8.1-py38haa95532_0
  python_abi         conda-forge/win-64::python_abi-3.8-2_cp38
```

I have tired all possible solution without a result, any hint?

Comment: What's the output of `import asgiref; print(asgiref.__version__)`?

Answer (score 2):

You should upgrade `asgiref`:

```
pip install --upgrade asgiref
```